# Разбить число на цифры

Tags: инспекция-кода, f#

На днях решил вкатится в F#. И в рамках поставленной задачи нужна функция разбивающая число на составляющие цифры. Сначала сделал через `ToString` и последующего каста `list<char>` в `list<int>` - работало, но как-то не спортивно все это. Переделал. И есть ощущение, что можно улучшить. Сделайте ревью, пожалуйста.

```
let gridWhith = 10

let getBalance value  = (value % gridWhith) 
let getQuotient value = (value / gridWhith) 

let rec getDigitsSeq (value:int)  =
    let acc = List.empty<int> 
    let balance = getBalance value
    let quitient = getQuotient value
    let reversedResult = 
        if quitient = 0 then value :: acc 
            else balance :: (getDigitsSeq quitient @ acc)
    List.rev reversedResult
```

Comment: Дайте вопросу нормальное название, плиз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Некоторые детали в коде можно опускать, потому что они дублируют друг друга. Про хорошую литературу говорят, что там нечего убавить, а не нечего прибавить.

```ml
let getBalance value  = (value % gridWhith) 
let getQuotient value = (value / gridWhith)
. . .
let balance = getBalance value
let quotient = getQuotient value
```

Можно написать проще

```ml
let balance = value % 10
let quotient = value / 10
```

Функции `getBalance` и `getQuotient` всё равно больше нигде не используются. Что происходит в коде, программисту понятно из-за названий `balance` и `quotient`.

Я бы убрал и `gridWhith`, если нет задачи написать универсальную функцию.

Теперь что касается самой функции. Она выглядит слишком императивно. Как это часто бывает в функциональном программировании, здесь удобно сделать внутреннюю рекурсивную функцию с аккумулятором, и вызывать её из внешней функции с корректным аккумулятором. В нашем случае это пустой список.

```ml
let digits number =
  let rec breakToDigits number list =
    let balance = number % 10
    let quotient = number / 10

    if quotient = 0 then balance::list
    else breakToDigits quotient (balance::list)

 breakToDigits number []
```

`break` означает *разбивать*. Если не ошибаюсь, *разбивать число на цифры* в английском выражается именно через *break*.

Comment: >Функции getBalance и getQuotient всё равно больше нигде не используются. На самом деле используются, на них много чего завязано еще, просто я вырезал из контекста)

Comment: пару поправок - `break` - зарезервированное слов, и блоке `else` пришлось добавить скобки `else breakNumber quotient (balance::list)` иначе не компилилось

Comment: @srvr4vr Понял, сейчас исправлю ответ. Набивал на ходу, под рукой Visual Studio не было, чтобы проверить.

Answer (score 0):

Еще неплохой вариант:

```
let digits number =
    let div a b = (a / b, a % b)
    let rec toList acc a =
        match div a 10 with
        | (0, w) -> w :: acc
        | (v, w) -> toList (w :: acc) v
    toList [] number
```